# When myd files will be created in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I am facing an issue which is,
java.sql.SQLException: Can't create/write to file 'xxxxx.MYD' (Errcode: 13)

But it has already executed some Alter queries.

My Question is, This error occurs because of permission(which is not enough to write a file), then how the another queries has executed?

Comment: what is this, a servlet container?

Answer (score 0):

.MYD is data file in myisam ENGINE tables as myisam tables contains 3 kind of files.

```
.frm : schema definition
.myd : data
.myi : index
```

First of all check if that is myisam file on which you execute alter and other updation at the time of this error or innodb.

Are u still getting this error or it was temporary at that time.

mysql has permission on your data directory as well /tmp partition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply  . . .

Comment: I am getting this error at every time. And I am using java code to execute alter queries. Also I didn't see any .myd file which contains table name. I need to know when these files will be created and what is myisam what is the purpose of these files? (I'm a fresher)

Comment: execute "show table status like 'mytable'" command and check what is engine of table....